# Connecting C# win32 app to Access Database

Tags: c#, ms-access, database-connection

I've been searching around to no avail for a supposedly simple connection to an `(MS)Access database (.mdb).`

I use `Office 2007, Visual Studio 2010,` it is a C# Winform application, on a x64 (64 bit) OS, with the app running in x86 (32 bit) mode.

I'm already able to easily access a SQL-server database but on (MS)Access I'm completely stuck.
I’m trying to connect to a database that is placed in my Dropbox.

My connection code:

```
//(string SQL = "select * from Quickmem";)

    public static DataTable SelectALL(string SQL)
    {
        var appDataPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(
                               Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
        var dbPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(appDataPath, "Dropbox\\host.db");

        var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(dbPath);
        var dbBase64Text = Convert.FromBase64String(lines[1]);
        string folderPath = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(dbBase64Text);

// Actual path (which he correctly finds): C:\Users\<username>\Dropbox
        folderPath += "\\Agenda.mdb";

        string strAccessConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= " + folderPath;

        string strAccessSelect = SQL;

        DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
        OleDbConnection myAccessConn = null;

        myAccessConn = new OleDbConnection(strAccessConn);


        OleDbCommand myAccessCommand = new OleDbCommand(strAccessSelect, myAccessConn);
        OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(myAccessCommand);

        myAccessConn.Open();


        myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "QuickMem");


        myAccessConn.Close();

        DataTableCollection dta = myDataSet.Tables;
        DataTable DT = dta[0];

        return DT;
    }
```

The current exception I’m getting is

> “System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException occurred
>    Message=Data type mismatch in criteria expression.
>    Source=Microsoft Office Access Database Engine
>    ErrorCode=-2147217913
>    StackTrace:
>         at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
>    InnerException: 
>   .”

In my experimenting, I’ve come across many issues all breaking on the same line:

```
myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "QuickMem");
```

Quickmem being a table in my database.

Any help or input will be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the *entire* stack trace, not just the message.

Comment: Please show the text of your sql command (strAccessSelect or SQL string)

Comment: OK, just finished installing MS Access on my machine, will play with it now... Also, why is your file saved as a .MDB when 2007 saves it as a .accdb

Comment: I used this page from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288452%28v=vs.71%29.aspx, So I manually saved it (using Save As) as MDB (2002/2003 DB)  to avoid complications, as it doesn't matter anyway for the DB itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made the following console app using a near identical copy of your code (I did comment out some lines which I've left for you to see)

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace AccessDb
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = SelectALL("SELECT * FROM QuickMem");
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static DataTable SelectALL(string SQL)
        {
            //var appDataPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(
                                   Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
            //var dbPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(appDataPath, "Dropbox\\host.db");    
            //var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(dbPath);
            //var dbBase64Text = Convert.FromBase64String(lines[1]);
            //string folderPath = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(dbBase64Text);

            string folderPath = "C:\\Users\\drook\\Documents\\Database1.accdb";    
            string strAccessConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= " + folderPath;    
            string strAccessSelect = SQL;    
            DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
            OleDbConnection myAccessConn = null;    
            myAccessConn = new OleDbConnection(strAccessConn);    
            OleDbCommand myAccessCommand = new OleDbCommand(strAccessSelect, myAccessConn);
            OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(myAccessCommand);

            myAccessConn.Open();    
            myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "QuickMem");    
            myAccessConn.Close();

            DataTableCollection dta = myDataSet.Tables;
            return dta[0];    
        }
    }
}
```

It compiles fine. It runs fine. There are no errors. Please note, I did comment some lines as I can't replicate them.

Therefore, the fault is either with your code before you even get to the database (where you are creating the folderPath) but since you've said you've now hard coded, it means it is unlikely.

The fault is either with the database itself (and please note I'm using the .accdb file extension, not the .mdb extension and also I only have 2 fields, ID and Text fields) or a configuration with your machine.

I'm sorry, this answer is probably better as a comment, but I can't place this much detail as such.

**EDIT**

Based upon your comments, please create a brand new WinForm and use this code - it will execute on load.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DatabaseCheckTest();
    }

    private void DatabaseCheckTest()
    {
        DataTable dt = SelectALL("SELECT * FROM QuickMem");
        MessageBox.Show("All done");
    }

    public DataTable SelectALL(string SQL)
    {
        string folderPath = "C:\\Users\\drook\\Documents\\Database1.accdb";    
        string strAccessConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= " + folderPath;    
        string strAccessSelect = SQL;    
        DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
        OleDbConnection myAccessConn = null;    
        myAccessConn = new OleDbConnection(strAccessConn);    
        OleDbCommand myAccessCommand = new OleDbCommand(strAccessSelect, myAccessConn);
        OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(myAccessCommand);

        myAccessConn.Open();    
        myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "QuickMem");    
        myAccessConn.Close();

        DataTableCollection dta = myDataSet.Tables;
        return dta[0];    
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried implimenting in what I already had, Didn't work, I'll try recreating your code.... Confirmed your code works, even when linking to Dropbox.

Comment: When you say it works, do you mean it works using the hard coded location of the database or the dynamically created version

Comment: Both, In fact, the console app works PERFECT, but EXACTLY the same code, does not work in my win32 app.

Comment: Hold on, will fire up a WinForm... And it works fine. I'm sorry, the fault you have is more complex. Please create a new WinForm and paste the code in my new edit

Comment: it indeed does work, thanks, it must then be somewhere else. thats good enough for now, I'll find the bugger ;)

Comment: Thank you @GordThompson, I'm sure we all remember how frustrating things like this are when you're by yourself or just starting! It's just good we have SO! :)